# How to determine that JAXB is done marshalling to file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

On a server there is a process that picks up files from a specific directory every specific interval (say 5 minutes).
The files that are being pickup is are generated by a webservice.
JAXB marshalling converts the files from objects to xml files.
The issue is it occurs frequently that files are being picked up before they are done.
A solution is to place the files in a temp directory or give them a temporary specific extension to let the polling process know to skip these.
Afterwards the files can be moved to the processing directory or extension can be changed so that the polling process can pick them up.

The method looks like this;

```
    private void writeToFile(Object obj, String outputFileName) {
    LOG.debug("Executing operation writeToFile using filename '{}' and object of type '{}'.", outputFileName, obj.getClass());

    try {
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = JAXB_CONTEXT.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, new File(outputFileName));
        LOG.debug("Wrote request to file '{}'.", outputFileName);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occurred while writing request to file:", e);
    }
    LOG.debug("Done executing operation writeToFile.");
}
```

My question is hot to dtermine that the marshalling proces is done so that the file can be released for further processing?

Comment: caould you try the outputFileName with different extension say .xmlpartial after the jaxbMarshaller.marshal add a line to rename the file back to .xml extension, that way you can make sure the watcher picks up the xml file once it is done

Comment: That is fine, yes, but how do I know when marshalling is done? That is the essential issue which I am stuck with.

PS: I was more thinking of an extension like 'lck', but everything is fine realy.

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback) afterMarshal

Comment: I have looked at this, and I do not know how to implement this functionality.
As far as I have understood, I need to set up listeners in the marshalling method, and create a class that execute code that is triggered by these listeners right after the marshalling has done?

Comment: https://turreta.com/2017/03/07/jaxb-perform-pre-and-post-processing-with-unmarshaller-listener/

Comment: Hey Saran, first I want to thank you for all your time and effort in helping me, the example you gave is regarding unmarshalling, not marshalling, I have searching still for a good example regarding marshalling but I can't find any.

Comment: please look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download the code from this link [https://turreta.com/2017/03/07/jaxb-perform-pre-and-post-processing-with-unmarshaller-listener/] Add the below Person Marshall Listener code to the source, as this will be called for each node have checked the root Node instance inside of Person (this needs to be modified as your base node) in both before and After Marshall Methods, also used a count of 2 because the start and end node calls this each time, as this should be called only on end node check if count == 2

```
package com.turreta.jaxb.unmarshaller.listener;

    public class PersonMarshallListener extends javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.Listener {

            int beforeCount = 1;
            int afterCount = 1;

          @Override
           public void beforeMarshal(Object source) {
              super.beforeMarshal(source);
              if (source instanceof Person) {

                  if (beforeCount == 2) {
                      beforeCount = 1;
                      System.out.println("BEFORE MARSHAL");
                  } else {
                      beforeCount++;
                  }
              }

           }

           @Override
           public void afterMarshal(Object source) {
               super.afterMarshal(source);

               if (source instanceof Person) {

                   if (afterCount == 2) {

                       afterCount = 1;
                       System.out.println("AFTER MARSHAL");
    //                 System.out.println("This will be called once the marshall has been completed");
                   } else {
                       afterCount++;
                   }
               }


           }

    }
```

And replace the DemoApp with the following code

```
package com.turreta.jaxb.unmarshaller.listener;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class DemoApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/person.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        PersonUnmarshallListener pul = new PersonUnmarshallListener();
        unmarshaller.setListener(pul);

        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
        System.out.println(person);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setListener(new PersonMarshallListener());
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);


    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I have used your adaptation of the code and it works. Now to make sure that I understand this.The afterMarshal method in PersonMarshallListener checks if the source object is an instance of Person, if so, it will count the nodes to determine whether it is within the root node or not. Because the person XML knows only one XML element, so the next must be the Root node. Am I correct? If I am, what about if I do not know many nodes I have before I reach the root node? Thanks, you have been a great help!

Comment: _Am I correct?_ No. The xml can have any number of nodes, we don't need to worry about that. In the xml from the source you downloaded, the Person is the root element, the count 2 is (<person></person>) both comes as true when checked for instance of person. as we need only the  completion details, we are restricting to use only the end node. So we check  `if (afterCount == 2) {`.

Comment: You have made it clear. Thank you for your time and effort, greatly appreciated! Accepted as answer.

Comment: No problem, happy that it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, how I solved it (Spring Integration)

You create a buffer to store files that are not old enough and process them later.

I know it is not perfect (with the sleep), but it works. The better solution is not working with file-exchanges, but transferring the data with REST-api's.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class LastModifiedFileReadingMessageSource implements MessageSource<File> {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LastModifiedFileReadingMessageSource.class);
    private final MessageSource fileReadingMessageSource;
    private final List<Message<File>> buffer = Lists.newArrayList();
    private final long age = 60;

    public LastModifiedFileReadingMessageSource(MessageSource fileReadingMessageSource) {
        this.fileReadingMessageSource = fileReadingMessageSource;
    }

    public Message<File> receive() {
        Message<File> message = fileReadingMessageSource.receive();
        while (message != null) {
            if (isOldEnough(message)) {
                return message;
            } else {
                buffer.add(message);
                log.info("Buffering file which is not old enough: {}; Buffer size: ", message, buffer.size());
            }
            message = fileReadingMessageSource.receive();
        }
        while (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
            message = buffer.stream().filter(this::isOldEnough).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (message != null) {
                buffer.remove(message);
                log.info("Use file from buffer: {}; Buffer size: ", message, buffer.size());
                return message;
            }
            sleep();
        }
        return message;
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            log.info("Go to sleep for a while... ({} seconds)", age);
            Thread.sleep(this.age * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Thread.sleep was never a good idea ;(", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isOldEnough(Message<File> message) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        return (message.getPayload().lastModified() / 1000 + this.age <= now);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not know how to implement this in my code example. I am new to webservices and jaxb.